# Read from MS SQL Server 2016 filestream and loaded into another winapp directly. Possible?

Tags: .net, sql-server, filestream, sql-server-2016

There is a filestream data table in SQL Server 2016 include different types of files such as jpg, mpeg, docx, xlsx, pdf and ...

Is there any way to open file in clients without save the stream on the client?

for example, first record contains a PDF file and I want to open PDF viewer and view its content without saving stream as a file on the client (Open on the fly). Actually read stream from SQL and send it directly to a WinApp. Additionally some WinApp such as Word should be able to save changes on the stream.

Comment: Use [FileTables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server).

Comment: You are right. FileTable shows all files and folders and the problem is "All users can see the structure and content of it via sharing system" but I don't want to see the contents via share folder.

Comment: Then deny permission for listing files on the folder (while still leaving SQL Server with full permissions). This will not prevent applications from opening files if they know the exact name, but they will not be able to discover other files. Doing this requires some [careful fiddling with permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/458611/ntfs-share-allow-file-read-deny-list-folder), but it can be done.

Comment: FileTable does NOT obtain NTFS permissions.